android 14 Exception on devicepolicymanager.wipedata(): User 0 is a system user and cannot be removed
I use DevicePolicyManager to do hard reset with wipe data in my device owner app. It works good, but on android 14 throws exception: "User 0 is a system user and cannot be removed ". I tried to pass different flags, but nothing helped. Are there any solutions for android 14 to call data wipe?
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            mDevicePolicyManager.wipeData(DevicePolicyManager.WIPE_RESET_PROTECTION_DATA)
        } else
            mDevicePolicyManager.wipeData(0)


found solution! in api34 there is a new method wipeDevice(). https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#wipeDevice(int)
and it works good:
fun hardReset() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
            mDevicePolicyManager.wipeDevice(DevicePolicyManager.WIPE_RESET_PROTECTION_DATA)
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            mDevicePolicyManager.wipeData(DevicePolicyManager.WIPE_RESET_PROTECTION_DATA)
        } else
            mDevicePolicyManager.wipeData(0)
    }


But you need to be Device Owner for this instead of Device Admin...

how can you be a device owner, instead of a device admin ? I have the same issue after targeting Android 14
